# In-app purchase crashes in monotouch ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

I developed an application for iphones by using monotouch and there is in-app purchase in it, i used this code https://github.com/Clancey/ClanceyLib/blob/master/ClanceysLib/AppStore/InAppPurchaseManager.cs . Everything works fine. I can purchase and i can get answer.

But sometimes i m getting error and then app crashes. For example i m trying to purchase 10 times by closing and reopening app. I m getting this error 2 times. App Store rejects my application because of that.

The error is : "Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used by your application."

Please help me how i can solve it.

BTW i m calling in-app purchase as below:

```
InAppPurchaseManager obj_inapp=new InAppPurchaseManager();
if (obj_inapp.canMakeProUpgrade())
{
inapp.PurchaseProUpgrade();
}
```

and if you need i can send logs, monotouch and xcode are the latest versions...

This is sample app : http://85.195.84.6/guessme/inapppurchaseproblem.zip

Regards...

Best Regards...

Comment: Post your stacktrace, off hand hard to tell the problem.  One thing to try is to store your InAppPurchaseManager in a member variable of your class.  I could see where the GC could collect it with your code sample above.

Comment: This is crash log  : http://85.195.84.6/guessme/ipad.rar

This is sample app : http://85.195.84.6/guessme/inapppurchaseproblem.zip

Regards...

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am having the same problem and I am curious how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try declaring `private InAppPurchaseManager inapp;` as a member variable within your controller's class?

As a local variable the GC could collect it and Objective-C would no longer be able to call back to C# and a crash would result.